# Chrome extension in react/typescript can you move the popup window itself?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a chrome extension currently. However I don't enjoy the standard position of the popup window. I want to know if I can adjust the position of the popup when it shows up or if there is anyway to override the default position?

-( sideNote: I am aware that I could inject my own elements and css, this post is not about that.)

Many thanks

Comment: No, but you can show a separate window via chrom.windows.create or add the popup as a DOM element inside the web page.

Comment: yep ended up going with window.create. - fit my needs better, thanks!